# как подключить встроенную библиотеку в visual studio c#

Tags: c#, библиотеки, поиск-библиотек

как подключить встроенную  библиотеку в  visual studio c# (БИБЛИОТЕКА  System.Windiws.Forms.Cursor ).Новичок не знаю как видео не помогают потому что новый visual studio 2017

Comment: `System.Windows.Forms.Cursor` - это ни разу не библиотека. Если на каждый класс по собственной библиотеке выделяться будет, ничем хорошим это не закончится ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

В проекте правой кнопкой по References(Ссылки) -> Add Reference(Добавить ссылку) появится окно для поиска, там в Assemblies ищем `System.Windows.Forms`

Comment: Держу пари студия на русском ) Добавьте локализированную версию

Comment: Ссылки - Добавить ссылку если что)

Comment: @Anatol даже не знаю как там, всегда английская была)